# TCP chat in Python 3.9 - ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

i am creating a private chat server and client with python 3.9, it was working perfectly until i decided to add an admin user with a password and the ability to kick and ban other users.

Now when i start the server and try to login from the client the server crashes and shows me this error: **ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**

I tried to turn off the firewall and any anti-virus softwares but nothing solved my problem, my network configuration has not changed since i created the original program.

here there is the server code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 55555

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = message = client.recv(1024)
            if msg.decode('ascii').startswith('KICK'):
                if nicknames[client.index(client)] == 'admin':
                    name_to_kick = msg.decode('ascii')[5:]
                    kick_user(name_to_kick)
                else:
                    client.send('Bel tentativo...'.encode('ascii'))
            elif msg.decode('ascii').startswith('BAN'):
                if nicknames[client.index(client)] == 'admin':
                    name_to_ban = msg.decode('ascii')[4:]
                    kick_user(name_to_ban)
                    with open('bans.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(f'{name_to_ban}\n')
                    print(f'{name_to_ban} bannato!')
                else:
                    client.send('Bel tentativo...'.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                broadcast(message)
        except:
            if client in clients:
                index = clients.index(client)
                clients.remove(client)
                client.close()
                nickname = nicknames[index]
                broadcast('{} uscito dalla chat!'.format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
                nicknames.remove(nickname)
                break

def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("---------------------------------------")
        print("Connesso con {}".format(str(address)))

        client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))

        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')

        with open('bans.txt', 'r') as f:
            bans = f.readlines()

        if nickname+'\n' in bans:
            clients.send('BAN'.encode('ascii'))
            client.close()
            continue

        if nickname == 'admin':
            client.send('PASS'.encode('ascii'))
            password = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')

            if password != 'password':
                client.send('REFUSE'.encode('ascii'))
                client.close()
                continue

        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print("Nickname: {}".format(nickname))
        client.send('Connesso al server!'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send("-------------------------------------".encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        broadcast("{} entrato in chat!".format(nickname).encode('ascii'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

def kick_user(name):
    if name in nicknames:
        name_index = nicknames.index(name)
        client_to_kick = clients[name_index]
        clients.remove(client_to_kick)
        client_to_kick.send('Sei stato buttato fuori!'.encode('ascii'))
        client_to_kick.close()
        nicknames.remove(name)
        broadcast(f'{name} buttato fuori!'.encode('ascii'))

print("Ascoltando...")
receive()
```

and here the client:

```
import socket
import threading

print("-------------------------------------")
nickname = input("Scegli il tuo nickname: ")
if nickname == 'admin':
    password = input("Inserisci la password: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55555))

stop_thread = False

def receive():
    while True:
        global stop_thread
        if stop_thread:
            break
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK':
                client.send(nickname.encode('ascii'))
                next_message = client.serv(1024).decode('ascii')
                if next_message == 'PASS':
                    client.send(password.encode('ascii'))
                if client.rect(1024).decode('ascii') == 'REFUSE':
                    print("Password sbagliata!")
                    stop_thread = True
                elif next_message == 'BAN':
                    print('Connessione negata, sei bannato!')
                    client.close()
                    stop_thread = True
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("Errore!")
            client.close()
            break

def write():
    while True:
        if stop_thread:
            break
        message = f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
        if message[len(nickname)+2:].startswith('/'):
            if nickname == 'admin':
                if message[len(nickname)+2:].startswith('/kick'):
                    client.send(f'KICK {message[len(nickname)+2+6:]}'.encode('ascii'))
                elif message[len(nickname)+2:].startswith('/ban'):
                    client.send(f'BAN {message[len(nickname)+2+5:]}'.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print("Comandi accessibili solo a admin!")
        else:
            client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Do somebody know what could be my problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does 'bans.txt' exist, and if yes, what is its content?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes, it exists, it is just an empty .txt